# Why does a new page disrupt \hypersetup, and is there a workaround?

Tags: hyperref, metadata

There is some strange behavior with new pages *(thanks to David Carlisle for noting that it is is not only `\clearpage`)* in that disrupts the ability to `\hypersetup` later in the document.

I generate my metadata after a new page, therefore I need to somehow store this data for the next run.

See the demonstration below for details.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % typeset with xelatex
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\insertproducer{placeholder}
\hypersetup{pdfproducer=Tester Schmoe (set in preamble)}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \renewcommand\insertproducer{Tester Schmidt (set in body just before end)}
  \hypersetup{pdfproducer=\insertproducer}
}%

\begin{document}
\null
%\clearpage % <-- uncommenting this results in \hypersetup failure
\end{document}
```

## `pdfinfo test.pdf` Output (commented `\clearpage`)

Expected output.

```
Creator:        LaTeX with hyperref package
Producer:       Tester Schmidt (set in body just before end)
CreationDate:   Tue Jun  7 12:13:48 2016
Tagged:         no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter)
File size:      2149 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

## `pdfinfo test.pdf` Output (uncommented `\clearpage`)

Unexpected output.

```
Creator:        LaTeX with hyperref package
Producer:       Tester Schmoe (set in preamble)
CreationDate:   Tue Jun  7 12:16:44 2016
Tagged:         no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter)
File size:      2138 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

Comment: it's not clearpage it's just any page break, the settings are the settings in force when the first page is shipped out (just how pdf backend works) so if you have more than one page your AtEndDocument setting has no effect

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your setup in several ways.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{pdfproducer=Tester Schmitty (set in preamble)}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \hypersetup{
    pdfproducer = \myproducer,
  }
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\myhypersetuptoaux[1]{% command to tell LaTeX to save the value for the next run
  \AtEndDocument{%
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\my@producer{#1}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\my@producer}[1]{\protected@xdef\myproducer{#1}}
\newcommand*{\myproducer}{% initial value
  This baby needs extra TLC, run it again.%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\null
\clearpage
\myhypersetuptoaux{Tester Schmoe}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get from `pdfinfo` after the first run

```
Title:          
Subject:        
Keywords:       
Author:         
Creator:        LaTeX with hyperref package
Producer:       This baby needs extra TLC, run it again.
CreationDate:   Thu Jun  9 09:17:16 2016
ModDate:        Thu Jun  9 09:17:16 2016
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter) (rotated 0 degrees)
File size:      8416 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

and this is what I get after the second run:

```
Title:          
Subject:        
Keywords:       
Author:         
Creator:        LaTeX with hyperref package
Producer:       Tester Schmoe
CreationDate:   Thu Jun  9 09:20:39 2016
ModDate:        Thu Jun  9 09:20:39 2016
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter) (rotated 0 degrees)
File size:      8389 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

## AUX File Solution

This could potentially be simplified and may have weaknesses. I am just starting to experiment with writing/reading AUX files.

**It is very important to note that certain things MUST be set early in the document:**

```
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=red,
    urlcolor=red,
    hyperfootnotes=false,
    hypertexnames,
    bookmarks=true % Causes clash if hyperref parameters loaded before bookmark, because bookmark loads hyperref without any parameters
}
```

1. This writes the metadata to the aux file as:

e.g.

```
\mysetproducer{Tester Schmoe}
```

2. The next run parses aux immediately after `\begin{document}` and executes:

e.g.

```
 \mysetproducer{Tester Schmoe}
```

which in turn creates a command `my@pdfproducer` containing `Tester Schmoe`

e.g.

```
 \expandafter\xdef\csname my@pdfproducer\endcsname{#1}}
```

3. The user-level command `\myproducer` grabs this value if the macro exists (only after aux file has been create--aka after at least one run)

e.g.

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname my@pdfproducer\endcsname\relax This baby needs extra TLC, run it again.\else
\csname my@pdfproducer\endcsname\fi}
```

## Full Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % typeset with xelatex
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{atveryend}

\hypersetup{pdfproducer=Tester Schmitty (set in preamble)}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \hypersetup{
    pdfproducer = \myproducer{}
  }
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\myhypersetuptoaux[1]{% command to tell LaTeX to save the value for the next run
  %\AfterLastShipout{%
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    %\protected@write\@mainaux{}{%
      \string\mysetproducer{#1}%
    %}%
    }%
  %}%
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mysetproducer}[1]{% called by the aux file and creates command my@producer that expands to input of myhypersetuptoaux
  \expandafter\xdef\csname my@pdfproducer\endcsname{#1}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\myproducer}{% user-level command to retrieve value of my@pdfproducer
  \expandafter\ifx\csname my@pdfproducer\endcsname\relax This baby needs extra TLC, run it again.\else
  \csname my@pdfproducer\endcsname\fi}
%  \@ifundefined{stored@#1}{???}{\csname stored@#1\endcsname}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\null
\clearpage
\myhypersetuptoaux{Tester Schmoe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Maybe you could help me out on my answer. I am wondering why my code fails when `\myproducer{}` is called without the trailing `{}` scope. I'm sure it is an easy fix!

Comment: you defined `\newcommand*{\myproducer}[1]` so it takes an argument so without the `{}` then it would take the `\end` from `\end{document}` as `#1` but I have no idea what you want the intended behaviour to be here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Duh. I'm an idiot. Thanks for catching that.